# MongoDB Aggregation of a user and his groups

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have 2 collections, "user" and "group" and I wanna return an object of a user and his groups.

The user is something like

```
{
    "_id": "5dea1ad0df42010984d1036f",
    // more info
}
```

and the group

```
{
    "_id": "5dea1ad0df42010984d1566a",
    "members": [
        { 
            "_id": "5dea1ad0df42010984d1036f", 
            "fullName": "Example", 
            "img":"https://example.com",
        },
        // more objects like that
    ]
}
```

Still didn't find a proper way of doing it, I'd be happy if someone can guide me/explain!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [$lookup with custom pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries):

```
db.user.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "group",
            let: { user_id: "$_id" },
            pipeline: [
                { $match: { $expr: { $in: [ "$$user_id", "$members._id" ] } } }
            ],
            as: "groups"
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/omXhtY2HoZy)

Comment: Thanks it worked!! I just added .toArray() to return that array inside the user's object :) Thanks again!